# Application running nginx server not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, capistrano

I have a rails application in Digital Ocean, running nginx, ubuntu 14.04, postgresql and capistrano.

The problem is that when I access my server address (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) it doesn't show up, that happened after I did a push to the server with `cap production deploy`, I have done these commands as well:

`sudo service nginx restart`
`sudo service nginx reload`
`touch tmp/restart.txt`

And nothing, and when I check up the configuration file status with `sudo nginx -t` it says:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Why is happening that? Any clue?

Here's my nginx.conf file:

```
user deploy;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Phusion Passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed passenger or passenger-enterprise
    ##

    passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
    passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/ruby;

    # passenger_root    /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
    # passenger_ruby /usr/bin/passenger_free_ruby;

    ##
    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    }


    #mail {
    #       # See sample authentication script at:
    #       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
    #
    #       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
    #       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
    #       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
    #
    #       server {
    #               listen     localhost:110;
    #               protocol   pop3;
    #               proxy      on;
    #       }
    #
    #       server {
    #               listen     localhost:143;
    #               protocol   imap;
    #               proxy      on;
    #       }
    #}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you paste your nginx.conf file please? Also, what's the output of `ps aux | grep nginx`

Comment: @DaniG2k i added de code i have on nginx.conf, and the output i got from the command you gave me is in here: http://pastebin.com/VM2RNNsb

Comment: It looks like your using Phusion passenger with nginx (I mention that because you state you ran `touch tmp/restart.txt`, what error / message are you getting when you try to access the server IP?  Also, as a side note you can run a service called BIND which will translate a IP address to a domain name so you won't have to type the IP address to access the server.

Comment: I would also post the output of the `access.log` and `error.log` in your question.

Answer (score 1):

First off, if your application is using PostgreSQL, make sure it's up and running as expected with the correct user, databases and tables.

Then, you might want to check that the `passenger_root` and `passenger_ruby` directives are correct. I have the following:

```
passenger_root /home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/passenger-5.0.18;
passenger_ruby /home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/wrappers/ruby;
```

Also, I'm not sure whether it's correct to have the SSL configuration within your http block. I believe that SSL directives belong within an https block. You also need to make sure that the `user deploy` exists and is correct.

I see that you have this directive as well:

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

you will need to ensure that there is a file within /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ that defines a server block that points to your website, as such:

```
server {
  listen                80;
  server_name           <some IP address here> yourdomain.com;
  root                  /home/youruser/yourwebsite/public;
  passenger_enabled     on;

  location ~ ^/(assets)/ {
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    gzip_static on;
  }
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root   html;
  }
}
```

(This configuration assumes you have a Ruby on Rails website. You'd need to adjust accordingly for your application.) The fundamental part here is the `server_name` directive which tells Nginx to respond to that DNS entry and do something.

Can you please also find the specific error message that you are encountering. You might want to look at the nginx logs or your application's logs to see what the error is.

Comment: Do I need to put a domain on *server_name* ? What if I don't currently have one? Right know I have it like the example **yourdomain.com**

Comment: if you don't have a domain, remove the domain name and just put the IP address that's been assigned to you.